# Cannot edit pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Somebody gave me their admin account of a website made using Wordpress. I can log into the wp-admin page of the website but the index page does not show the Pages section at all. The only things available are Dashboard, Jetpack, Profile, and Visual Composer. The dashboard gives the message that there is 'no activity yet!' Is this account not the admin account or something went wrong? Would appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Can you not edit the pages, or can you not see any pages?

Comment: I cannot see any pages so I can't edit them.

Comment: Are you sure that someone already created pages on this account? Can you access them from outside?

Comment: Are you sure that you've permissions to edit pages?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the user don't have sufficient permissions with which you are logging.

Answer (score 0):

After logging in to the admin panel, open the page of the website from front end(not admin panel). On the top right you should get EDIT option, IF you have permissions to do so.